# Bootstrap grid does not initialize, but all other features are fine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

After a week of researching the the issue, I arrive here.

The basic idea is I need three columns to hold my content. The final version will be three circles of images of album art that link to album releases. For now, I used 'placeholder text' for simplicity's sake.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <section id='media' class='media-section'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
            <h1>Media</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4"><p>Placeholder text1.</p></div>
           <div class="col-md-4"><p>Placeholder text2.</p></div>
           <div class="col-md-4"><p>Placeholder text3.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When running locally, the placeholders display on top of one another, as they would normally. As far as I am aware, they should be evenly spaced in line with one another with 30px gutter in between.

The link to my Bootstrap is

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Your div closing tags don't match, but that might be copy paste error from actual problem?

Comment: Take this bootstrap file: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css